# get a specific node from sceneView in arkit

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
```

I added node as above. 
but I want to get node and edit something...

but...how can I get a node?

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
            node.enumerateChildNodes{(node, stop) in

                     What should I do in here? 

                })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want to get node and edit something, when you add the node, name it with

```
node.name = "yourNodeName"
```

then get with:

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
    if node.name == "yourNodeName" {
       //edit something
       node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you : ) I successfully get a noe that I want . 
but...to delete only that node...what should I do ? I only used to do removeAllParentNode() method...I can't see others that delete only one node.

Comment: Updated answer for deleting only that node